# FxCop spell check trips on company name in namespace

Tags: fxcop, spelling

I am trying out FxCop (through the UI for the moment, not included in CruiseControl.NET etc.) and am running into some issues. It seems the spell checker does not like my client's company name and the product name and it asks me to:

```
Correct the spelling of 'CompanyName' in namespace 
name 'CompanyName.Product.TimerJobs.FeatureReceivers'.
```

- Do  I write a rule for this, if so, how?
- Or is there a way to add to the dictionary?
- I also have some Dutch language parameters (they are bound to Sharepoint parameters in an `ObjectDataSource` so they need to stay Dutch, because client wants that), can I somehow add the Dutch library to FxCop?

**Edit**

I have found the `CustomDictionary.xml`, but is this considered best practice? What about if more people join the team would they need a copy of the dictionary, or is it better to move to continuous integration?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You should keep `CustomDictionary.xml`, as well as the FxCop project file under version control, along with the rest of the project. This way everyone gets the dictionary, and continuous integration can also pick it up.

About the Dutch spell checking... I think your best option would be to either:

1. Add the "offending" parameter names to the dictionary
2. Manually exclude the rule violations

I prefer nr 2 because it is more specific and won't allow using those dutch names anywhere else.